# Menu is not showing in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu

[image: something like this m trying to achieve]

My requirement is simple, I want to open list of menuItems in fragment. So I created menu XML inside menu and trying to inflate inside **onCreateOptionsMenu**  method in Fragment  but unfortunately nothing is showing.

Here is:

**myFragment.java**

```
public static MoreFragment newInstance() {
        return new MoreFragment();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.more_drawer, menu);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_more, container, false);

        setUp(v);

        return v;
    }
```

here is,
**more_drawer.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_busTracking"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_drawer_bus_tracking"
            android:title="Bus Tracking" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_kidsWallet"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_drawer_kids_wallet"
            android:title="Kids' Wallet" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_circlals"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_drawer_circulars"
            android:title="Circulars" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_message"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_drawer_messages"
            android:title="Messages" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_accountSettingd"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_drawer_account_settings"
            android:title="@string/account_settings" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_drawer_logout"
            android:title="Log Out" />

    </menu>
```

**fragment.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried **setHasOptionsMenu(true)**  put inside onCreate() and onCreateView() but nothing is showing.

I tried debug and find that **onCreateOptionsMenu()** is not called. I tried all the solution provided to this question but nothing goes in my favor.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท that method it self is not called

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.more_drawer, menu);

    }
```

To:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.more_drawer, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    }
```

And use: `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` after view inflates-creates:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Comment: same result nothing is coming:(

Comment: `public static MoreFragment newInstance` are using this at the first line of defining `Fragment`? Also, i have updated the answer with `onActivityCreated`.

Comment: newInstance method used to replace my fragment and now its coming  but its coming in actiob bar right side

Comment: Is that the Fragment whole code? If not, would you paste all of it? Also, try adding `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` after `View v = inflater.inflate`. It should work with these changes.

Comment: Glad to hear that pal!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your Manifest file?

Make sure the Theme you choose for the activity includes the action bar.
e.g:android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">